# Chrome cut off Oswald-Light font

Tags: css

I am using **Oswald-Light** font family it is fine on FF and IE but cut off on Chrome
[image]

Comment: Have the same problem. It's even not working on Google webfonts page http://shrani.si/f/10/wU/xqBhso9/google-web-fonts.png

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the `font-weight` property to `normal`.

This recently worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer for your problem:
https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=152

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you install Oswald on your pc/Machine.............Happened to me it drove me nuts for hours. After removing the font everything came back to norma

Answer (score 0):

From what I learnt, it's partially Chrome font cache being broken. To fix your OS X font cache, clear it using

```
   $ atsutil databases -removeUser

    And then restart the font server using

    $ atsutil server -shutdown
    $ atsutil server -ping
```

I hope this will helpful to you.